# Sum and Group By Clause

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a Table as shown below

```
Name         Id         Sub1        Sub2 
Raj          1           75          76   
Ramesh       2           85          58   
Sekhar       3           65          55   
Siddharth    4           95          85    
Raj          1           52          75   
Sekhar       3           97          95   
Siddharth    5           78          85
```

I need an output as follows

```
Name         Id       Sub1     Sub2 
Raj          1         127      151  
Ramesh       2          85       58   
Sekhar       3         162      150    
Siddharth    4          95       85  
Siddharth    5          78       85
```

That is I need to have sum of the marks in the subject column and group by the Id column. I need to display the Name but it should not be included in the GroupBy clause. 
How should I write the query to get the desired result? Thanks in advance.

Comment: so if, for example, Id 2 gets grouped, that means the name displayed should be Ramesh (first = min(Name)) or Sekhar (last = max(Name))? You have to decide how columns should get aggregated if they are not contained in the group by clause.

Comment: what isthe real ID of `Sekhar`? is it `2` or `3`?

Comment: How come  `sum` of Raj in `sub2` is 152 which should be `76+75=151` and `shekhar` to be `55` ?

Comment: Sorry i missed the calculations.. Let me modify it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :-

```
with cte as 
(  Select row_number() over(partition by a.id order by a.ID) rn,
   a.name,a.id , b.sum1, b.sum2  from
   sample a
   inner join 
  ( Select id,sum(sub1) Sum1,sum(sub2) as sum2 
    from Sample 
    group by id)b
  on a.id=b.id
)
Select name,id,sum1,sum2 from cte where rn=1
```

or you also use `Sum` and `Over` clause with `Subquery`

```
 Select *
 from 
 (
  Select name,id,sum(sub1) over (partition by id) sub1,
  sum(sub2) over(partition by id) sub2,
  row_number() over(partition by Id order by id) rn
  from sample
 ) s
 where rn=1 
 order by s.name
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7d9eb/14) Demo

Comment: Based on all the various comments/clarifications to the question, I would say the second query here looks like the best option available. The only thing that's missing is a better column for ordering the `row_number` clause; there's no guarantee of consistent results just ordering by Id. Hopefully the OP can supply a bit more information about the table and perhaps some sort of time column to use in `row_number` that would get everything working.

Comment: Second query is work for me and easy to understad... thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like after all the clarifications it's really just as simple as:

```
select Name
  , Id
  , Sub1 = sum(Sub1)
  , Sub2 = sum(Sub2)
from MyTable
group by Name, Id
order by Id
```

[SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9555d/1).

Comment: The Name column must not be included in the GroupBy Clause.That's where I got trouble.

Comment: Why can you not include the Name in the Group By? You're displaying it in the query results so it should be included. The query results are exactly what you require.

Comment: It's like i have more columns like address, first name, last name also in my actual scenario. So there is a possibility that the address might have been modified so I cannot include all those columns in groupby clause. Sorry for not listing all those columns.

Comment: You need to give more information in the question, then... Is everything stored in the same table? Is there another table that stores the information you want in its latest form? You need to show a specific example showing where a column has been modified in your table and how you want to handle it in the end result set.

Comment: Yes everything is stored in the same table. Is there some other way to add the Name to the result without including it in the GroupBy Clause?

Comment: Based on all of the above, I would look at the answer provided by @praveen below... It's missing one last part (how to order the results to make sure you're getting the name, adddress, etc you want) but will be your best option.

Answer (score 0):

If you're needing to exclude `Name` from the group by clause, assuming your id is a unique identifier and only ID's are only assigned to 1 name, aggregate `Name` using `MAX()`

```
SELECT
    MAX(Name) AS [Name]
   ,Id
   ,SUM(Sub1) AS [Sub1]
   ,SUM(Sub2) AS [Sub2]

FROM
    MyTable

GROUP BY
    Id

ORDER BY
    Id
```